# Lightning Component Validation: Is there a way to extend to show warnings?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation

As per [Lightning Components Developer Guide - Validating Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm) I know its possible to perform validation in the client-side controller/helper and then push updates to the UI through:

```
inputCmp.set("v.errors", "You cannot do this");
```

This will highlight the field and display the message in red underneath. Awesome.

I was wondering, is it possible to do something like the following:

```
inputCmp.set("v.warnings", "Be careful about doing this");
```

This would highlight the field and display the message in orange (or some other colour) underneath.

Comment: You might need to head towards implementing it via custom CSS. For an instance, you could have some help text under the field with some specific color to it.